# Apache to nginx subfolder rewrite for ckeditor

Tags: apache, nginx, ckeditor

I am using Laravel forge for provisioning webservers and works great right out of the box.
I now encounter the following customer question that I can't seem to manage solve.

In the folder of /file/ckeditor/php/ there is a .htaccess with the following contents.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file/ckeditor/php/file(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ index.php [L]
```

So basically the request of /file/ckeditor/php/link should rewrite to /file/ckeditor/php/index.php.
The rewrite rule must be skipped when there is no /file/* in the end. I have a current nginx configuration of the following, but maybe I need to set a new document root and a new php handler?

```
root /home/forge/faked-domain.nl/public;

index index.html index.htm /lib/blue2.php;

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|webp|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /lib/blue2.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/faked-domain.nl-error.log error;


location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

error_page 404 /lib/blue2.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index /lib/blue2.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Hope someone can help me out..

Comment: Is the folder `/file/ckeditor/php/` under `/home/forge/faked-domain.nl/public`?

Comment: yes it is, it uses the same folder only a level deeper

Comment: You have various locations that process URIs with specific file extensions, so its difficult to know how those will interact with the requirements for ckeditor. You can try a simple emulation of the `.htaccess` rule with a negative look-ahead assertion. Try: `rewrite ^(/file/ckeditor/php)/(?!file(/.*)?$) $1/index.php last;` outside any of your `location` blocks.